# Update order items based on product quantities

Tags: java

I have 2 classes Order & OrderItem as below

```
public class Order {

    private String orderId;
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems;

}

public class OrderItem {

    String productId;
    Long price;
    Integer quantity;

}
```

I want to implement function update orderItems based on product quantities based on this requirement: When an user update quantities of items, If given products are not found in the given order, add those items newly to the order.If given quantities are zero in the given order, delete those items from the order. Otherwise update the quantities of order items.

My algorithm for this requirement as below:

```
List<OrderItem> request

List<OrderItem> data
```

> Processing on request
>
> - Filter any req item has qty = 0 into a Set name deletedItems
> - The rest request collection is for update & insert
> - Convert the rest req collection in to Map<productId, OrderItem>
>
> Processing on data
>
> - Filter data items with deletedItems
> - The rest collection iterate to update, if productId exists in Map then update, remove that item from Map
> - Insert newly items in the rest of Map into data items

```
void updateItems(List<OrderItem> request, List<OrderItem> data) {
    Set<String> deletedItems = new HashSet();
    Map<String, OrderItem> reqItems = request.stream()
            .map(x -> {
                if(x.getQuantity() == 0) {
                    deletedItems.add(x.getProductId());
                }
                return x;
            })
            .filter(x -> x.getQuantity() > 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(OrderItem :: getProductId, x -> x));

    data.stream()
            .filter(x -> !deletedItems.contains(x.getProductId()))
            .map(x -> {
                String productId = x.getProductId();
                if(reqItems.containsKey(productId)) {
                    x.setQuantity(reqItems.get(productId).getQuantity());
                    reqItems.remove(productId);
                };
                return x;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    reqItems.entrySet().stream()
            .forEach(x -> data.add(new OrderItem(x)));
}
```

Does my algorithm is ok? Any suggestions for improvement? Thanks

Comment: What is your exact question? I cannot really see a definite algorithm. Since you seem to use Java or C#, maybe provide your algorithm in source code. Then, however it would rather be a question for codereview.stackexchange.com. Also consider tagging the used language.

Comment: It's java, I just post my code

Comment: Okay, then this question is indeed off-topic here and appropriate exactly for [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

here a simple way

```
void updateItems(List<OrderItem> request, List<OrderItem> data) {
        request.forEach(r -> {
            final Optional<OrderItem> exitsOrder = data.stream().filter(d -> d.getProductId().equalsIgnoreCase(r.getProductId())).findFirst();
            if (exitsOrder.isPresent()) {
                if (r.getQuantity() == 0) {
                    data.remove(exitsOrder.get());
                } else {
                    exitsOrder.get().setQuantity(r.getQuantity());
                }
            } else {
                data.add(r);
            }
        });
    }
```